# Does Skyrim auto-save after I level up?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

If I level up on my character (full level, not a skill), does the game automatically save?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While I can't speak for Xbox 360 (although it's likely the same or similar), the system settings menu in the PlayStation 3 and PC versions has four options:

- Save on Rest (on/off)
- Save on Wait (on/off)
- Save on Travel (on/off)
- Save on Character Menu (5, 10, 15, 30, 45, 60 minutes or disabled)

And, even considering the possibility that they don't enumerate all possible autosave opportunities in the settings, it did not save after I leveled up: no message in the upper-left hand corner, no lag associated with autosaving, and the autosave functionality kicked in on schedule at the 15 minute mark later on.

I then confirmed this by loading my last auto save, which was before I leveled up.

So level up has no effect on autosaving.